# How to extract street address from any classified ads?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, information-retrieval, opennlp

There are a lot of classified ads appearing in NON-HTML format(paper ,text ,written ,etc) which tend to sell house,automobile,rent,lease,flat,etc. A classified ads say for example, a flat rent ad has some of the features included like: SIZE,AREA,LOCALITY,PRICE,CONTACT INFO. .etc

My question is how to extract the street  address(address mentioned in article /LOCALITY) in which the ad resides or has mentioned in former article ?

Is there any solution to this problem using NLTK & python ??
Imagine that the source of article is in normal text file(.txt) .

Comment: can you provide a text paragraph of your example data?